# Modelling "sibling" relationship of tables with foreign keys in multiple tables in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

There are two tables, let's call them `Source1` and `Source2`, they both have the usual `id` and other irrelevant columns. Then there's table `Product` that has foreign keys to both `Source1` and `Source2`, the two foreign keys make up `Product`'s primary key (in other words, there's one-to-one relationship between `Product` and the cartesian product of `Source1` and `Source2`). Then there's another table `MultiProduct`, again having foreign keys to both `Source1` and `Source2`; its primary key is composite of both foreign keys and a third field. In flask-sqlalchemy's declarative language, the schema so far looks like this:

```
class Source1(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    # ...
class Source2(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    # ...
class Product(db.Model):
    source1_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Source1.id'), primary_key=True)
    source2_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Source2.id'), primary_key=True)
    multis = db.relationship('MultiProduct', ...)  # 1) what goes here?
    # ...
class MultiProduct(db.Model):
    source1_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Source1.id'), primary_key=True)
    source2_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Source2.id'), primary_key=True)
    extra_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    product = db.relationship('Product', ...)  # 2) what goes here?
```

This essentially leads to `Product` and `MultiProduct` being in one-to-many relationship and this is the relationship I'm struggling to describe - I'd like `Product` to have a list of `MultiProduct` objects and `MultiProduct` to have a single `Product` object - the lines marked with "what goes here" are not very clear to me. Both suggestions on how to do this and how to simplify my database schema are appreciated.

My attempts have been along the lines of

```
    multis = db.relationship("MultiProduct", backref='product', uselist=True,
        primaryjoin="and_(Product.source1_id==MultiProduct.source1_id,"
                    "Product.source2_id==MultiProduct.source2_id)",
        foreign_keys=[source1_id, source2_id])
```

with or without `__table_args__`:

```
    __table_args__ = (
        db.ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['source1_id', 'source2_id'],
            ['MultiProduct.source1_id', 'MultiProduct.source2_id'],
        ),
    )
```

in either/both of `Product` and `MultiProduct` (with the proper corresponding table name). When doing `Product(multis=[MultiProduct(...)])`, I get an exception saying `MultiProduct`'s `source1_id` is null, violating a constraint i.e. the "child" `MultiProduct` doesn't get the ids from the parent.

What's the correct way to model this? Is my database schema sub-optimal from the start?